# How to get day of month to calculate total sales in PHP and Mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my project I want to accomplish. Input data from user and automatically creating the date modified.

Input and list of result on the loop is fine. But now I want to do the calculation for the total sales by month and year.

Database column style example: `model_name`, `sold_date`, `sold`, `stock_left`

The date is using `NOW()` on my PHP inserting code, so the result stored on database will be `2015-04-06`.

Each sale will have its own created date.
Example:

```
name  sold     date 
item1  3      2015-04-06
item2  4      2015-04-06
item1  4      2015-04-07
```

I want to grab the day of the date 2015-04-**06** and sum the total sales for each item. And show up the monthly sale even for the yearly sale.

My thinking is that:

```
SELECT YEAR(sold_date) AS 'year', 
       MONTH(sold_date) AS 'month' 
FROM Table 
WHERE Condition = 'Condition';
```

But to show the result of loop, I need to:

```
$mysqli->query("SELECT * 
                FROM item 
                ORDER BY sold_date DESC  
                LIMIT $start,$per_page");
```

Those two sql command seems cannot combine together or I don't know how to combine them.
Or after combining them, how to sum the totals.
Final sales table will be like this:

```
name   month  total
item1 04(Apr) 7
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you can use DAY(`<date>`), MONTH(`<date>`) or YEAR(`<date>`) to get the coorisponding day, month and year from date.

Comment: thx for replying. how to do that, I am thinking <select DAY(sold_date), sold_quantity from item where model_name="$modelName";> kinda this way?

Comment: Yes.  Just put the DAY() part right in front and surrounding the column name.

Answer (score 1):

To get day from date:

```
$timestamp = strtotime('2009-10-22');
$day = date('d', $timestamp);
$month = date('m', $timestamp);
$year = date('Y', $timestamp);
```